# react.js not refreshing state update with date value

Tags: reactjs, view, rendering

This is a simple react code,

```
import { useState } from "react";
export default function App() {
  const [dateValue, setDateValue] = useState(new Date());
  const dateUpdate = () => {
    const newDate = dateValue;
    newDate.setMonth(dateValue.getMonth() + 1);
    console.log(newDate);
    setDateValue(newDate);
  };
  return (
    <>
      <div className="App">{dateValue.getMonth()}</div>
      <div>
        {" "}
        <button
          onClick={(e) => {
            dateUpdate();
          }}
        >
          Click
        </button>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

However, the date value changes show updated values in the console output, but are not reflected in the view, the output remains the same.

If we simply add another state value, it redraws the view, but why don't it with the date field alone? wondering the theory behind it.

Comment: for reference, the above code is available in the codesandbox. Please refer. 

https://codesandbox.io/s/datevalue-state-update-check-i6tn8v?file=/src/App.js:0-545

Answer (score 1):

There is a minor mistake in your code:

Instead of this: `const newDate = dateValue;`
Do this: `const newDate = new Date(dateValue);`

The reason: You need to tell react that there is an update by wrapping it in new Date() since `dateValue` and `newDate` will reference to same.

Here is the full code mate:

```
import { useState } from "react";
export default function App() {
  const [dateValue, setDateValue] = useState(new Date());
  const dateUpdate = () => {
    const newDate = new Date(dateValue);
    newDate.setMonth(dateValue.getMonth() + 1);
    console.log(newDate);
    setDateValue(newDate);
  };
  return (
    <>
      <div className="App">{dateValue.getMonth()}</div>
      <div>
        {" "}
        <button
          onClick={(e) => {
            dateUpdate();
          }}
        >
          Click
        </button>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: "The reason is pretty obvious" is not very helpful, at least add a more detailed explanation since the OP is clearly not so experienced with JavaScript :)

Comment: Thanks for the insight mate. Updated my reason :)

Comment: Yes, the new reference works well, but without it itself, the console shows the updated value. 
So the assumption is that React understands the value change but the React view does not since the vDom points to old reference? @Harry

Answer (score 1):

React re-uses the previous render output, for performance reasons, because the references to all previous states are unchanged.

When you call `setDateValue(newDate)` you are not actually updating state from the perspective of React, because `newDate` and `dateValue` are the exact same reference.

In order to inform React that there is new state, you need to update state with a new reference with something like `const newDate = new Date(dateValue);` instead.

Comment: Ok, so it seems the React view update process does not recognize the state change though the state value gets updated internally and the view does not since its an object reference?